# PHP Array with double values

Tags: php

I'm beginning with PHP and I would like to get your help in order to populate array with double value.

I have this little script :

```
$liststatus=array(
    '-1'=>$langs->trans("Draft"),
    '1'=>$langs->trans("Validated"),
    '0'=>$langs->trans("Resiliated")
);
```

I would like to add `'10'=>$langs->trans("Validated")`. In this way, validated search button should displays `$liststatus` with both values `'1'` and `'10'`

I tried :

```
$liststatus=array(
    '-1'=>$langs->trans("Draft"),
    '1'=>$langs->trans("Validated"),
    '10'=>$langs->trans("Validated"),
    '0'=>$langs->trans("Resiliated")
);
```

But it displays twice validated button.

So How I can write something like this :

```
'1' && '10'=>$langs->trans("Validated")
```

I tried this syntax but it doesn't work.

Thank you :)

Comment: How you work with `$liststatus` array? This code displays nothing.

Comment: The issue is in the code that processes this array, not in the array creation. Show us that code

Comment: You can fileter the array on value. Or use value as key and key as value.

Comment: https://eval.in/918260

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh: i'm not sure if the question is _how to add && into array key?_ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Array or hash need to have Key and Value.

What you did here is correct as both ket '1' and '10' pointing to value 'Validated'.

```
$liststatus=array(
   '-1'=>$langs->trans("Draft"),
   '1'=>$langs->trans("Validated"),
   '10'=>$langs->trans("Validated"),
   '0'=>$langs->trans("Resiliated")
);
```

Or if you really hate see 'Validated' repeated there, you can split it into two arrays.

```
$listStatusText = [$langs->trans("Draft"),
                   $langs->trans("Validated"),
                   $langs->trans("Resiliated")];
$listStatus=array(
    '-1'=> 0,
    '1' => 1,
    '10'=> 1,
    '0' => 2
);

echo $listStatusText[$listStatus[$x]]; // $x is your key value.
```

Comment: Why so complicated with another map when you can simply do `$liststatus['10'] = $liststatus['1'];` or even `$liststatus['10'] = &$liststatus['1'];` to have a real reference to the element? But that's not really an answer to the problem OP is facing.